# Hibernate UUID generator in a single non identity field

Tags: java, hibernate, uuid

I'm trying to force hibernate producing UUID field in DB model but the problem is that this field is not a primary `@Id` field and cannot be done in this way.

My model looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myModel")
public class MyModel {
    private Long id;
    private UUID uuid;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY", length = 16)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to implement this strategy?

**UPDATE:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myModel")
public class MyModel {
    private Long id;
    private UUID uuid;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY", length = 16)
    @Type(type="uuid-binary")
    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }
}
```

**Note:** `@GenericGenerator` is no longer necessary so has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

For this below code can be used

```
public UUID getUuid() {
    return uuid == null ? UUID.randomUUID() : uuid;
}
```

It is quite late to post this, but it might come help to some one else.